# how to initialize std::map as a class member

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How can I initialize `std::map` variable in my class.

Currently my code is not compiling and i am getting error.

```
Error   C3376   'SumCommandInterface::call_function': only static data member templates are allowed
```

Code:

```
class SumCommandInterface
{

private:
    std::string stdstrCommand;
    std::map < std::string, PluginTypeLookUp > lookUpPluginMap;

 // I want to initialize this member
    template<typename plugin>
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(plugin* plug, const std::string &, const std::string &)>> call_function;

public:
    SumCommandInterface();  
    int receiveCommand(std::string stdtsrCommand , const QModelIndex & RootIndex , TreeModel *myModel);
    bool getTreeItem(const std::string &stdstrName , const QModelIndex & RootIndex, TreeModel *myModel , TreeItem** item );
    template<typename plugin, typename fieldType>
    inline void setFontPluginParam(plugin* geom, std::string paramName, fieldType val);

    template<typename plugin, typename fieldType>
    inline void setTexturePluginParam(plugin* geom, std::string paramName, fieldType val);

    template<typename plugin>
    void stringFunction(plugin* plug , const std::string& name, std::string stdstr);

    template<typename plugin>
    void intFunction( plugin* plug, const std::string& name, std::string stdstr);

    template<typename plugin>
    void floatFunction(plugin* plug , const std::string& name, std::string stdstr);

    template<typename plugin>
    void boolFunction(plugin* plug , const std::string& name, std::string stdstr);

};


template<typename plugin, typename fieldType>
inline void SumCommandInterface::setTexturePluginParam(plugin* plug, std::string paramName, fieldType val)
{
    CommandInterfaceTexture commandInterface;
    Sum_Texture_2D *texture = plug;
    commandInterface.SetValue< Sum_Texture_2D >(texture, paramName, val);
}

template<typename plugin>
void SumCommandInterface::stringFunction(plugin* plug, const std::string& name, std::string stdstr)
{
    setFontPluginParam<Geometry , std::string>(plug, name , stdstr)
}

template<typename plugin>
void SumCommandInterface::intFunction(plugin* plug, const std::string& name, std::string stdstr )
{
    setFontPluginParam<Geometry, std::string>(plug, name, std::stoi(stdstr));
}

template<typename plugin>
void SumCommandInterface::floatFunction(plugin* plug, const std::string& name, std::string stdstr)
{
    setFontPluginParam<Geometry, std::string>(plug, name, std::stof(stdstr));
}

template<typename plugin>
void SumCommandInterface::boolFunction(plugin* plug, const std::string& name, std::string stdstr)
{
    setFontPluginParam<Geometry, std::string>(plug, name, (stdstr == '0' ? false : true ));
}
```

This should be the defination

```
template<typename plugin>
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(plugin* plug, const std::string &, const std::string &)>> call_function =
{
    {"TEXT", SumCommandInterface::stringFunction },
    {"USESHADOW", SumCommandInterface::boolFunction },
    {"FONTSIZE", SumCommandInterface::intFunction },
    {"SHADOWDISTANCE", SumCommandInterface::floatFunction },
    {"SHADOWOPACITY", SumCommandInterface::floatFunction },
    {"KERNING", SumCommandInterface::floatFunction }
};
```

Comment: There are to many unimportant stuff in code included and most important part is missing or have not enough context. Please provide [mcve] (reduce problem) using one of the online tools: https://godbolt.org/ https://wandbox.org/ or whatever you like.

Comment: You want some template instances, for each type "plugin" a new one and all of them should be initialized to the same values?

Comment: @Marek R i have updated the code .

Comment: @Klaus  i have updated the code.

Comment: Can you please answer the question? I did not see any relevant change from your last edit. I can't catch what you want to achieve. A template var with all the same content? Sorry, can't catch the sense

Comment: "only static data member templates are allowed". Which part of this sentence is unclear to you?

Comment: Unrelated, but `SumCommandInterface::stringFunction` is a non-standard MSVC-ism. You need an `&` to take an address of a member function.

Comment: This is because the map expects a `std::function<void(plugin* plug, const std::string &, const std::string &)>` which is not a member function (and you try to pass a member function, so it does not match). The compiler tells you that if you really want to do this, the function must be `static`. Because if it is not, it depends on a class instance (which is not the case of what is expected by the map). Or you have to find another way to achieve it as @MarekR proposed as an answer.

Comment: @Fareanor this is indeed a problem but not the one that causes this particular error message.

Comment: This looks like a problem that would be more suitably solved with inheritance and polymorphism. (It also looks like you have some fundamental misconceptions about templates, but it's not obvious what they are.)

Comment: I've provided answer, but for me it looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I've got feeling that this template is an overkill. OP should describe what functionality he tries to provide (probably in separate question).

Comment: @shomit You should also remove all your templates and create only one template over the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok now I see the problem.

It should go like this:

```
// template<typename plugin> // this is problem too - see below!
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(plugin* plug, const std::string &, const std::string &)>> call_function =
{
    {
        "TEXT",
        [this](plugin* plug, const std::string &s, const std::string &s2)
        {
            SumCommandInterface::stringFunction(plug, s1, s2); };
        }
    },
    {
        "USESHADOW",
        ...
    },
};
```

Note to `std::function` you have to provide function which matches declaration inside `std::function` and your `SumCommandInterface::stringFunction` reqiried implicit argument `this` (regular methods are invoked for specific object).

So as a solution I used lambda expression which captures missing `this`.

Also there is a problem with template. You can't declare class field as template. Only methods can be a template or whole class can be a template, not a field.

Here is minimal complete demonstration that it works: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PAMGV04fr0BN4ueb
I'm unable to quickly fix your code.

Comment: where should i write this , in the class constructor ?

Comment: @Marek R i am getting error C2059 syntax error: '}'

Comment: @n.m. here is a demo https://wandbox.org/permlink/PAMGV04fr0BN4ueb for simplified example.

Comment: @shomit Yes, there is a typo, an extra '}'.

Comment: @Marek the simplified example leaves out the template thing. Which, incidentally, is exactly the thing that causes the error message in the first place. So while the simplified example does indeed work, it has the meat simplified out of it.

Comment: @n.m. I've wrote about that at the bottom (his code has two issues) before I've provided an example and then made template parameter a class parameter.

Comment: @Marek it's OK now, provided that OP can indeed make it a class template.